# Come si traduce in italiano "first cousin once removed"?

Tags: english-comparison, translation

Si tratta, in inglese, del/della cugino/a di mio padre/madre, ma non credo che esista una terminologia precisa nella nostra lingua... voi sapete aiutarmi?

Comment: O il cugino di mio nonno!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il cugino del padre o della madre, o la cugina, non sembra avere un nome specifico in italiano. In alcune regioni si chiamano "[zii cugini](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/zio/)". I loro figli sono tuoi cugini di secondo grado.

In inglese invece tu e il cugino di tuo padre siete "first cousins once removed". Non ho mai sentito una simile terminologia in italiano.

Comment: Concordo sui cugini di 2 grado, ma non sul prozio, che è il fratello del nonno ( it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parentela#Proz.C3.ACo.2Fprozia) . Forse il cugino del padre potrebbe essere di 2 grado anche lui?

Comment: Grazie, hai ragione! Ho corretto e aggiunto una fonte. Non sembra che in italiano esistano nomi specifici per parentele lontane.

Comment: grazie! avevo questo dubbio da quando mi sono interessato di genealogia e ho scoperto che invece in inglese hanno nomi per quasi ogni tipo di parentela...

Comment: Spesso ho sentito parlare di cugini di secondo grado anche per i cugini di primo grado dei genitori. Lo [schema](http://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parentela#Schema) su Wikipedia sembra corroborare questa interpretazione, mentre d'altra parte il testo non dice nulla in proposito. Ha l'aria di essere la classica questione confusa all'italiana =)

Comment: io pensavo che il cugino di mio padre fosse mio zio di secondo grado. In pratica pensavo che gli zii di n-esimo grado fossero quelli raggiungibili (solo) risalendo di `n+1` generazioni e poi ridiscendendo di `n` generazioni l'albero genealogico, mentre pensavo che i cugini di n-esimo grado fossero i loro figli (per cui: `n+1` generazioni in su e altrettante in giù)

Answer (score 0):

I think that one solution, reported also by treccani is "procugino", neverheless it is not clear if you refer to your parents' cousin or to the son of your cousin.
 Procugino/a is a useful word to enumerate the members of your family but not to explain who is who.
The better solution is to translate it as " il/la cugino/a di mio/a padre/madre"

Comment: The English term is ambiguous in the same way: there is a one-generation difference between you and your first cousin once removed, but it can be in either direction: either I am one generation older than my FCOR, or my FCOR is one generation older than me.